# Format text file for the LOAD DATA INFILE command

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working in a company where I have this project to create a web application based on the products my company is making.

There is an inside server which contains all the data from my company. What I have to do is parse the data the oracle server is retrieving. It is retrieving .lst files which can be easily translated to .csv using Excel or some php packages.

I successfully imported the Clients table into my MySQL database using the LOAD DATA INFILE command. But I'm running some issues when I want to parse the Articles table.

The columns/values aren't necessarily separated by semi-colons. To parse the data I'll have to say for example :

- The first 6 characters are the Article ID
- The next 35 characters are the description of the article

and so on...

Is there a way I could achieve this when using the LOAD DATA INFILE command, or should I format the file correctly using PHP then use this command and if so what could be the best approach?

Thanks guys, I hope I made myself clear since english isn't my primary language. :P

Edit : those are rows.

```
51016 51016 BOITE ORANGINA 33cls CASHS   "24"                               040430024000330  0000000000            1       01000000550009000                   000000NNNNNN caisse         0000003750000000000001230      
51019 51019 BOITE OASIS ORANGE CASHS  "24" 33cl                             040430024000330  0000000000            1       01000000550009000                   000000NNNNNN caisse         0000003670000000000001230
```

The first line is getting parsed correctly while the second isnt.The double quote after 24 is being put into the next column. I just wanted to know if it was possible to do something about it, like deleting the double quotes.

A previous developer created an application to manage the articles, clients from the company. Unfortunately he cannot help me anymore but here is a ligne that describe a row.

```
import_a;Code_article;6;designation;35;designation2;35;Code_famille;2;Code_sousfamille;4;unite_condition;3;contenance;6/1000;Champ_vide;2;degre;4/10;champ_vide_6;6;Code_emballage;4;Champ_vide2;8;validite;1;Champ_vide3;7;code_tva;2;taux_tva;9/100;poids;6/1000;champ_vide4;19;montant_droits;6/1000;valide;1;rupture;1;edit_tarif;1;pre_commande;1;gratuit_autorise;1;trans_port;1;Champ_libre;1;caisse;15;prix_revient;9/100;stock;6/1;Champ_vide5;5;code_fournisseur;11/1
```

import_a => It's the filename you can just ignore that.

Then you have the name of the column followed by the number of characters. For example Code_articles is composed of 6 characters and so on.

You can also just ignore the duplicate ID Key at the beginning. **But in total there should be 31 columns.**

Comment: reading a text file and parsing it should be an easy job. You can add some logic after the parsing, then write the adjusted lines to the csv file. You can actually parse the .lst file directly without using Excel. If your .lst file is very large, you may not want to do the parsing or the importing from web script. Instead you can do it on the back end using a perl script or C/C++ binary.

Comment: Hm, how should I handle this script? I mean on the server side. My .lst file is indeed very large.

Comment: You can schedule a Perl script, which reads your lst file, transforms it to csv and calls the mysql load file command, on your server.

Comment: I see. Is parsing .lst files the same as parsing .txt file? I got no experience with perl whatsoever. I already parsed many XML/Json files in the past using Java/objective-C/C# but this is different. Isn't this going to be hard? I mean, I got something like 5k rows to parse and parsing them seem to be tedious. Should It be something like : Read line 1, format line 1, write it on the .csv file, Go back to .lst file and so on. Or should I store all of my values in an array and write the .csv file from it, i'm a bit lost.

Comment: If you need help, try post a few lines of your lst file (if it's text format) and i can post you a perl script to parse the file and write into a csv format.

Comment: I've edited my question for clarity. If you could give me a heads up that's be great. :) Just so I can use it to get started and develop mine after learning perl. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a fixed width text file. But the description doesn't match the data. for example, there are two codes in the beginning. I don't see the 4th cell "Code Famille" with 2 chars either. Show us some lines of your transformed csv file.

Comment: Yes, as I said ignore the duplicate key at the beginning. The "Designation" for the line one is "SEPTICLADE BIDON 5 LITRES" but also all the blank space until the next numbers. "Code_famille" are the 2 chars so for the first it would be 09. "Code_sousfamille" would be "0910" and so on.

I also cannot give you the formated .csv since excel can only format files when they are separated by a semi colon for example. In my case the data isn't separated by anything.

There should be 31 columns, but excel creates a csv file with only 10 columns.

Comment: And I don't see the two 35 characters designations. The space between the second codes and the the next code is about 64 characters.

Comment: Same here. But it's just a line I've picked up from a program so I cannot tell you much. But for sure there are two "designation" columns, and the "code_famille" starts at 09. Here's what it should look like in the end : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wmW0qu1K

Comment: I posted a perl script for you to start the transforming. You need finger out the real format of your data. Adjust the $def line by giving different width to each column , until you see the correct output. If you need filter out some values, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this perl script to start your testing. The most important thing is the adjust the $def line according to your real data, until your get the correct result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$input_file = "/tmp/a.lst";
$output_file = "/tmp/a.csv";
$testing = 1;  #testing, print out directly first 100 lines

# we are using tab (#9) for the output csv file
$delim   ="\t";

# output column header 
$output_header = 1;

$defs= "import_a;Code_article;6;Code_article2;6;designation;29;designation2;35;Code_famille;2;Code_sousfamille;4;unite_condition;3;contenance;6/1000;Champ_vide;2;degre;4/10;champ_vide_6;6;Code_emballage;4;Champ_vide2;8;validite;1;Champ_vide3;7;code_tva;2;taux_tva;9/100;poids;6/1000;champ_vide4;19;montant_droits;6/1000;valide;1;rupture;1;edit_tarif;1;pre_commande;1;gratuit_autorise;1;trans_port;1;Champ_libre;1;caisse;15;prix_revient;9/100;stock;6/1;Champ_vide5;5;code_fournisseur;11/1";

my @input_fields, @input_fieldwidths, @input_fieldwidth_max, $input_field_no =0;
@defs= split(";",$defs);
$total_defs=$#defs;
$total_cols = 0;
$total_width = 0;

for($x=0; $x<$total_defs /2; $x++)
{
  push(@input_fields, $defs[$x*2+1]);
  $width = $defs[$x*2+2];
  if($width=~/(.*)\/(.*)/){
    $mw= $1;
    $xw= $2;
  }
  else{
    $mw = $width;
    $xw= 0;
  }
  $total_width += $mw;
  push(@input_field_widths,$mw);
  push(@input_field_widths_max, $xw);
  $total_cols ++;
}

if($testing){
  for($x=1; $x<$total_cols; $x++)
  {
    print "$input_fields[$x]: $input_field_widths[$x]\n";
  }
}

open(INPUT, $input_file) || die "Can not open input file";
open(OUTPUT, ">$output_file" ) || die "Can not open output file";

# this is the csv head
if($output_header){ 
  print OUTPUT "$input_fields[0]";
  for($x=1; $x<$total_cols; $x++)
  {
    print OUTPUT "\t$input_fields[$x]";
  }
  print OUTPUT "\n";
}

$lines=0;

foreach $l (<INPUT>)
{
  chop($l);
  $pos =0;
  for($f=0; $f < $total_cols; $f++)
  {
    $val = substr($l, $pos, $input_field_widths[$f]);
    print OUTPUT $delim if($pos);
    print $delim if($pos && $testing);
    print OUTPUT $val;
    print $val if($testing);
    $pos +=  $input_field_widths[$f];
  }
  print OUTPUT "\n";
  print "\n" if($testing);
  $lines++;
  if($testing && $lines>100) { last;};
}

print $lines , " lines transformed\n";

close(INPUT);
close(OUTPUT);
```

Edit: for a comma separated quoted csv format:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


$input_file = "/tmp/a.lst";
$output_file = "/tmp/a.csv";

# we are using tab (#9) for the output csv file
$delim   =";";
$testing = 1;  #testing, print out directly first 10 lines
$quote   ="'";

# output column header 
$output_header = 1;

$defs= "import_a;Code_article;6;Code_article2;6;designation;29;designation2;35;Code_famille;2;Code_sousfamille;4;unite_condition;3;contenance;6/1000;Champ_vide;2;degre;4/10;champ_vide_6;6;Code_emballage;4;Champ_vide2;8;validite;1;Champ_vide3;7;code_tva;2;taux_tva;9/100;poids;6/1000;champ_vide4;19;montant_droits;6/1000;valide;1;rupture;1;edit_tarif;1;pre_commande;1;gratuit_autorise;1;trans_port;1;Champ_libre;1;caisse;15;prix_revient;9/100;stock;6/1;Champ_vide5;5;code_fournisseur;11/1";

my @input_fields, @input_fieldwidths, @input_fieldwidth_max, $input_field_no =0;
@defs= split(";",$defs);
$total_defs=$#defs;
$total_cols = 0;
$total_width = 0;

for($x=0; $x<$total_defs /2; $x++)
{
  push(@input_fields, $defs[$x*2+1]);
  $width = $defs[$x*2+2];
  if($width=~/(.*)\/(.*)/){
    $mw= $1;
    $xw= $2;
  }
  else{
    $mw = $width;
    $xw= 0;
  }
  $total_width += $mw;
  push(@input_field_widths,$mw);
  push(@input_field_widths_max, $xw);
  $total_cols ++;
}

if($testing){
  for($x=0; $x<$total_cols; $x++)
  {
    print "$input_fields[$x]: $input_field_widths[$x]\n";
  }
}

open(INPUT, $input_file) || die "Can not open input file";
open(OUTPUT, ">$output_file" ) || die "Can not open output file";

# this is the csv head
if($output_header){ 
  print OUTPUT "$input_fields[0]";
  for($x=1; $x<$total_cols; $x++)
  {
    print OUTPUT "\t$input_fields[$x]";
  }
  print OUTPUT "\n";
}

$lines=0;

foreach $l (<INPUT>)
{
  chop($l);
  $pos =0;
  for($f=0; $f < $total_cols; $f++)
  {
    $val = substr($l, $pos, $input_field_widths[$f]);
    print OUTPUT $delim if($pos);
    #print $delim if($pos && $testing);
    print OUTPUT $quote, $val, $quote;
    if($testing){
      print $input_fields[$f] , "=", $val, "\n";
    }
    $pos +=  $input_field_widths[$f];
  }
  print OUTPUT "\n";
  print "\n" if($testing);
  $lines++;
  if($testing && $lines>0) { last;};
}

print $lines , " lines transformed\n";

close(INPUT);
close(OUTPUT);
```

Comment: Thanks that's really kind of you! Imma try this out, understand how this works and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: This is working wonderfully. By the way the duplicate ID Key was mixed with the "designation" column, so designation and designation_2 are 35 chars.

Just wanted to ask you a last thing : How do you add semi colon at the end of the columns? I've tried to add them myself without any success.

I did not really understand why there are 2 different loops at the end, it seems they both write on the output file.

Thanks again!

Comment: You can change the $delim to ";" to use semicolon. However, you may also have to add quote mark to values. The double loop is needed to output every values in each line and every line.

Comment: Where you would put the quote? Also, some lines aren't parsing properly because of double quotes.

Among 7k lines + there are something like 5 or 6 lines which aren't getting parse correctly. 

As an example : http://pastebin.com/pNPhxVSF

Wanted to know if I could so something about it and avoid having some designation_2 columns with blank double quotes.

Comment: This kind of data were not shown on your question. Please edit your question and post your code so we can edit for you.

Comment: Posted another format. Since your original code use single quote, I guess it's because of the values like "24" . The foreach $l line is to handle each input lines, the for loop inside is to process each values.